# Is “if they are still not…” right and what is an alternative way to phrase this?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, adverbs

The sentence was this:

> In his process of dying; the children, if they are still not independent of his guidance, shall perish.

The expression '*are still not*' does not seem grammatically correct.

What could be an alternative way of framing this sentence using 'still'?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145992/discussion-on-question-by-aurelius-is-if-they-are-still-not-right-and-what-is); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us ignore the curious punctuation up to and including the semi-comma and examine the clause you highlight.

*the children, if they are still not independent of his guidance, shall perish.*

Remove the double negative:

*the children, if they are still dependent of his guidance, shall perish.*

*Dependent of guidance* may be understood as *depending on guidance*

Tidy up:

*the children, if they still depend on his guidance, shall perish.*

From which it is clear any children who need the guidance of the dead or dying man will be unable to survive, because he can no longer guide them through the dangers that beset them. Only those who have become independent and need no guidance might survive.

Alternatively stated:

*the children who have not become independent of need for his guidance shall perish*

Comment: Is it ' if they will still depend on his......' or is "will" redundant here?